# Linking error with boost filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, codeblocks, mingw32

I just wrote a little program using the boost filesystem library. Now it comes with some weird linking errors.
I already tried reordering the libraries, checked compiler version used for the boost binaries (Boost 1.51.0; MinGW 4.7.1 static libraries) and my MinGW version - 4.7.1.

Has someone an idea what else the cause for this could be?

Thanks in advance.

The output of the linker was:

```
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5boost10filesystem6existsERKNS0_4pathE':
C:/boost_1_51_0/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:289: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)' 

obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5boost10filesystem4pathC1IA15_cEERKT_PNS_9enable_ifINS0_11path_traits11is_pathableINS_5decayIS4_E4typeEEEvE4typeE':
C:/boost_1_51_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:139: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits8dispatchISbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEEEvRKSsRT_RKSt7codecvtIwciE':
C:/boost_1_51_0/boost/filesystem/path_traits.hpp:174: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::basic_string, std::allocator >&, std::codecvt const&)'
```

I linked to the following libraries (set in Code::Blocks build options):

```
...\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw47-mt-d-1_51.a 

...\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw47-mt-d-1_51.a
```

The source Code (the interesting parts, i.e. the parts using boost):

```
//... 

#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED

#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

//...

int main()

{

    boost::filesystem::path p("./file.txt");

    if(boost::filesystem::exists(p)) cout 
//...

}

//...
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Thank you for providing details with your question. One more detail: what is the command line you used to link your program?

Comment: I compiled and linked it using Code::Blocks (not from the command line).

Comment: Is it possible to extract from Code::Blocks the command line that *it* used?

Comment: @marzipankaiser There must be a way to have Code::Blocks print out the command line it uses to call g++; it's difficult to know what's going on without looking at that. Also, the library path you've listed seems a little suspicious. `bin.v2` is the folder where Boost stores intermediate files during a build. The generated libraries are typically under `boost_1_51_0\stage\lib`.

Comment: It used the following (which should invoke the linker, too): g++.exe -LC:\MinGW32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1 -LC:\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib  -o bin\Debug\Util.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lstdc++  C:\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw47-mt-d-1_51.a C:\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw47-mt-d-1_51.a

Comment: @Praetorian: changed it now to the /stage/lib/ files (like you see in the command line), but the errors remain the same.

Comment: @marzipankaiser I know you've said you've done this already but can you rearrange the library order and verify that Code::Blocks preserves that order by looking at the command line? I have a project that uses Boost.Filesystem and MinGW, and my command line has `libboost_system*.a` listed before `libboost_filesystem*.a`

Comment: Changed order and checked command line: g++.exe -LC:\MinGW32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1 -LC:\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib  -o bin\Debug\Util.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lstdc++  C:\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw47-mt-d-1_51.a C:\boost_1_51_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw47-mt-d-1_51.a

Comment: But the errors stay the same...

Comment: works now. used new boost 1.53 libraries (compiled yesterday)

Comment: using -lboost_filesystem-mt option worked for me